# Drupal anonymous post linked to users

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, relation

I have a situation where anonymous users can fill an application using entityforms and send without registering on a site. Later on the anonymous user is expected to register for an account.
Now the anonymous user will in the entity form submit a field called email address.

Now I want to use that field to compare with current users email address and if a match is found, create a link between previous submissions and the user.

The two options, I have tried are views, creating a relationship between user and entity form through email field but that is not working

Also tried rules where data comparison is made between entity form email field and current user email field, I am aware the commerce guys have done the same thing on their commerce module to allow anonymous shoppers to submit carts.

The other solution could be populating hidden fields with cookies data and then creating a relationship between says session Id on post and user session Id.

Could someone shed light on the best approach and if possible some sample solution..

Answer (score 1):

I would do it through rules

1. Add Email to then entityform type
2. create a VBO Viewthat find entityform submissions.  It should have contextual filter for the email field
3. add a reaction rule for user being created
4. Add an action to Rule to load list from VBO using the user email to send the View
5. Loop through list and set uid property for Entityforms to user->uid

btw entityforms is my module.  Thanks for using it.